# How to prove the following strange relation concerning fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, fibonacci-numbers, products

Is the following relation concerning fibonacci numbers, $F_n$ true?
$$F_{2n-1}^n=2^{2n^2}\prod\limits_{r=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{s=1}^{n}\left(\cos^2\frac{r\pi}{2n+1}+\cos^2\frac{s\pi}{2n+1}\right)$$

I am dumbfounded seeing this expression. Is the expression true. If so, should we try to prove the expression taking only the portions inside the brackets, or should we make use of de-moivre's theorem, or, any recurrence formulae? Meanwhile, I know of this relation among Fibonacci numbers and trigonometric function:
$$F_n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\left(1+4\cos^2\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$. How could we use this expression in proving the above relation. The main relation arose from the formulae for finding the number of tilings of a chessboard using dominoes. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Does your formula work for $n=1$?

Comment: @CatalinZara edited my formula. It is difficult to verify even for $n=1$. I hope it does?!

Comment: @CatalinZara I just calculated. It doesent work for $n=1$. So, is it true for higher $n$ too?

Comment: @CatalinZara edited the formula again. This time, it works for $n=1$

Comment: I dont think is true, the right hand side is all Kasteleys theorem for domino tiling. The fibonacci of the left hand side implies that your dominos are probably in stripes of $2\times n$ dominos.

Comment: @Phicar no the left hand side is sequence of stripes of $2\times 2n$ dominoes, which makes for $2n\times 2n$ board.

Comment: Yes, but there are configurations left out. For example, rotate any of this configurations 90 degrees.

Comment: @Phicar ok, so waht should I multiply the left side by, so that the equation becomes alright. something like $F_{2n-1}^2$, that is, should the LHS be $F_{2n-1}^4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Too long to answer the comment:** This is not true. The right hand side counts the number of domino tilings of a square with dimensions $2n\times 2n$ and the left hand side can be thought as stacking $n$ times a stripe of dimensions $2\times 2n.$ In general there is no way you can go from one to another because there are configurations that can not be seen as a stripe of dominos. For example:

Notice also that the left hand side for $n=3$ is $6728$ and the left hand side is $25$ they are coprime, so you can not multiply anything to fix it. In particular consider the following tiling. 
[image]
Check that there is no way you can form this by just multiplying Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: thanks, so the derivation of kastelyn signing formula is not straightforward, right!

Comment: Nop, it needs a theorem in orientation of graphs. The book: A course in enumeration of Martin Aigner has a chapter on this.